# How to handle information about different sections with mysql/laravel

Tags: php, laravel, content-management-system

I need to build a webpage where you have a section that might return you to a different layout/view depending on the section you choose
Example

```
section www.mywebpage.com/products -> view/layout products.blade.php
section www.mywebpage.com/blog -> view/layout blog.blade.php
```

The thing is that product shares some database fields with blog like

```
|section|
---------
|title|
|header_image|
|layout| // to choose the section 
|slug|
```

and then other kind of info just related to the section itself

```
|blog|
-------
|descrition|
|main_text|
|section_id|

|products|
|section_id|
|...|
|...|
```

Is there anyway that there anyway to build this in Laravel? I'm having headaches thinking about and I couldn't find the better solutions.

I find hard to think how the code/models will be and I will have to create one table for each different section that I need that has another unshared field

Comment: Are you calling a single page a section?

Comment: You are looking for traits...

Comment: I will take a look on traits.

And yes, a page => section

Answer (score 0):

So, as I understand you mean the layout is dynamic ?!
if true those layouts should be exists in views/layouts folder

so in your Product controller you need to return the name of the layout and the same for the blog Controller

```
@section($layout)
..
@endsection
```

**Solution 2**

create your layouts and for product views call the product section layout and the same for blog

product.blade.php

```
@section('layouts.product')
..
@endsection
```

blog.blade.php

```
@section('layouts.blog')
..
@endsection
```

Comment: I clearly understand this, it's not about the layout (that's why the layout field in the database table) but the info given for each section. They share some info and the other they don't. The question was if I should create a database table for each section I have

Comment: Event the tables share same section, you don't need to use single view and handle it by using conditions, if you have pics so we can understand more because it is not clear enough for me

Comment: https://infiniemlabs.com.ar/Social/ https://infiniemlabs.com.ar/Industria/ imagine this, you see that Social and Industria shared some characteristics that might be on the "section" table, and then the layout it's completely different. What I want to know is HOW should I handle that different information  that each other has.